# Could I change the icon size of main application in QT?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, icons

Now I changed my QT application icon.

When program start, I can see the chaged icon in the top left side.

However, it looks very small so I`m trying to find that the icon size is adjustable.

I tried QMainWindow::setIconSize but it changed icon size in toolbar section.

If you have any knowledge about it please adivce me. Thx for reading. [image]

Comment: As far as I know the size of title bar, its icon, color and text are managed by your operating system.

Comment: I also think it cannot change T T. Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply an icon using your OS/IDE. I did this using Visual Studio. In my project's resource file (*.rc) I added line like the following:

```
IDI_ICON1       ICON        DISCARDABLE ".\\Data\\icons\\app.ico"
```

Such an .ico file must contain icons of multiple sizes. These sizes are used for different puroposes. E.g. certain magnifications in windows explorer or for the icon in the window titles. However you don't have direct control which size is used... the OS picks the icons sizes it needs.

Search in the web for corresponding informations. All the needed information is available.

Comment: Thx so much. Although the size didn`t chage, my app icon looks much better than before~~!!

Comment: "Search in the web for corresponding informations. All the needed information is available." Providing links, or links+quotes from sources, would be much more helpful.